# Folder path with functions in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm beginner in Laravel 5.8. 
I have Controller (MainController) in App\Http\Controllers.
I have file with functions in App\CMS\Engine\myFunctions.php

In MainController.php I want php require_once 'myFunctions.php'.
Which path should be included in this require_once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses **PSR-4/composer to autoload files**, assuming your file is namespaced correctly, you should be able to to just declare a use statement at the top or something like `\App\CMS\Engine\myFunctions (assuming myFunctions is a class with methods).`

If your `myFunctions.php` file is just functions, you need to add it to composer to autoload. something like:

```
"autoload": { "files": [ "app/CMS/Engine/myFunctions.php" ] }
```